# How can I access a shared folder from an Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Azure VM setup (dev1) and I cannot access a shared folder (publish) via UNC path from my workstation.  I am connected to Azure over a P2S VPN connection and my workstation is in the same domain as the Azure VM.  When I open explorer and try to access \dev1\publish, I get an error saying:

```
\\dev1 is not accessible.  You might not have permission to use this network resource.  
Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions."

The user name could not be found.
```

I am logged in to my workstation as a domain user and am never prompted to enter different credentials.  Am I misunderstanding how to access a file share on an Azure VM?

Comment: This should be asked on ServerFault.

Comment: Try utilise the IP address rather than the hostname.

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this? I find that my non-Win10 machines can access the Azure VM Share fine over P2S, but not the Win10 machines. Seems there is a bug with Win10...